# Spring boot date handling in application.yaml and properties

Tags: date, configuration, yaml, spring-boot

I am creating a simple spring boot application, that loads a string (ISO-date) from the application.yaml file and tries to put it into a @Value annotated field.
If I use a .yaml file the string is obviously converted into a date/calendar and afterwards "toStringed" into a different format.
If I use a .properties file the string is passed as-is.

Application

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        SampleComponent c = ctx.getBean(SampleComponent.class);
        c.bla();
    }
}
```

Component that should be configured

```
@Component
public class SampleComponent {

     @Value("${dateString}")
     private String dateString;

     public void bla() {
        System.out.println(dateString);
     }
}
```

application.yaml

```
dateString: 2015-01-09
```

=> Output: Fri Jan 09 01:00:00 CET 2015

application.properties

```
dateString=2015-01-09
```

=> Output: 2015-01-09

For me it is fine to use the properties solution, but I do not understand why this happens?

(Note: When trying to assign the yaml-date to a date field the expected "Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found" Exception is thrown)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happening because Spring Boot uses SnakeYAML for its YAML parsing and SnakeYAML's default behaviour is to create a `java.util.Date` from any string that it considers to be a timestamp. If you're interested in learning more, see SnakeYAML's [Resolver class](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/c3e98fd755a949f65cf11f2ff39e55a1c2afd1c2/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver.java) for further details including the regex it uses to identify a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, actually that is the problem. Still I would call it very unexpected behaviour, esp. as the date is converted back to string afterwards.

Comment: The behaviour surprised me too. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2422

Comment: The URL for Snakeyaml Resolver class is changed: https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/master/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver.java